# Find multiple distances in SQL with loop

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, stored-procedures, distance

I am working on a trucking problem where I have multiple distribution centers(DCs)  and multiple stores.  I have the longitude and latitude for both the DCs and the stores.  I'm not sure how to loop through the 47 different DCs longitude and latitude and the 4500+ stores longitude and latitude and then find the shortest distances of each.  I was thinking something like this (but I think the temporary table is wrong):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempStores AS (SELECT * FROM wm_stores)

SET i = 0;   
WHILE i <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tempStores) - 1 DO
    SELECT store_id FROM tempStores LIMIT i,1 INTO thisStoreID; 
    SELECT store_id FROM tempStores LIMIT i,1;

    SET  i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

DECLARE storeLat DOUBLE;
DECLARE storeLon DOUBLE;
DECLARE dcLat DOUBLE;
DECLARE dcLon DOUBLE;
DECLARE storeLatRad DOUBLE;
DECLARE storeLonRad DOUBLE;
DECLARE dcLatRad DOUBLE;
DECLARE dcLonRad DOUBLE;
DECLARE R DOUBLE;
DECLARE distance DOUBLE;
SET R = 3961;                     
SET  storeLat = 37.350659;    ## <-- Basically Loop this here
SET  storeLon = -76.734855;    ## <-- Here
SET  dcLat = 37.192498;        ## <-- Here
SET  dcLon = -77.534201;       ## <-- And here... instead of having it all hard coded.
SET  storeLatRad = PI() * storeLat/180.0;     
SET  storeLonRad = PI() * storeLon/180.0;    
SET  dcLatRad = PI() * dcLat/180.0;        
SET  dcLonRad = PI() * dcLon/180.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to, for each store, identify the nearest distribution centre?

To get this information, we're going to need to know the distance between each store and each distribution centre; You're proposing to do this in a loop, but if instead you just let SQL do it, and put all the data in a temporary table (or subquery) then I'd suggest the outline logic becomes something like:

```
SELECT y.StoreID, z.DCID, y.ClosestDCDistance as Distance 
FROM (
    SELECT StoreID, Min(StoreDCDistance) as ClosestDCDistance
    FROM ( SELECT StoreID, DCID, StoreDCDistance FROM TempTable ) x
    GROUP BY StoreID
) y INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT StoreID, DCID, StoreDCDistance FROM TempTable 
) z ON y.StoreID = z.StoreID AND y.ClosestDCDistance = z.StoreDCDistance
```

You could tidy this up with a CTE if you want. Irrespective, all that is required is to fill in TempTable (or make this logic a subquery if you prefer);

```
SELECT StoreID, DCID, (???) as StoreDCDistance INTO TempTable
FROM wm_Stores st, wm_DCs dc      -- haven't got name of DCs table
```

I don't know how to calculate the distance which I've put as ??? in parentheses, but presumably you've got this information already. I am assuming that an  equation is adequate to calculate the distance from LatA, LngA to LatB, LngB - though I'm not expecting the equation to be a simple A + B = C. Given what you've got above

(PI() * st.storeLat/180) is obviously one small component of it, but I can't guess what else is required, and your post doesn't show any calculation of an overall distance.

If a single equation cannot do the entire calculation, you'll need to use a function to calculate the distance given the values of LatA, LngA, LatB & LngB.

Hope this helps.